# Css mime type error in an express application

Tags: css, express

In my express application I included the CSS file like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\public\css\style.css">
```

You can see my project structure here:

https://www.screencast.com/t/bkMH5Xmrz

but it throws this error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I have tried different paths of the css file. It is a simple file. nothing other than:

```
#jumbo {
    background: #2980b9;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless I am missing something shouldnt your forwards slashes be backslashes? So it would look like this `href="/public/css/style.css"`

Comment: Change it to the backlashes but no luck

Comment: hmm one other thing i was thinking was add this `type="text/css"` to your css file call